# Bind class instance property to class extended type chain. Tell TS to allow JS "this" behaviour

Tags: typescript

For this snippet:

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        
    }
    // this method is called from child, 
    // so 'this' is type of Child and cosmisFunc exists
    callChildFunction() {
        this.cosmisFunc() // compiler error here: Property 'cosmicFunc' does not exist on type 'Child'.ts(2339)
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    someMethod() {
        this.callChildFunction()
    }

    cosmisFunc() {
        console.log('oh mama')
    }
}

//not meaningfull code... instance construction...
myChildInstance.someMethod()
```

I'd like to tell typescript that method will be called from child class in parent class to that this error ts(2339) is not thrown. Apparently typescript prevents you from calling `callChildFunction` with a different `this` which is allowed by JS. I was thinking there could/should be a way in typescript to tell the compiler that `this` will always by whithin the hierarchy propotipal chain (meaning that `this` will alway refer to a `Parent` or a `Child` instance).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gWAFDQOmAHsUI0EBXYNYhACgEos9C3pXCBfTg4MECADCACwCWIACYAxSihpjSTFvnYE04iADoSEALZiIs+coD0posT0AHCUgTR7COtBH2kALjjPr9tAE9oAHJdA2BjYCDoSWIkGBRiDCQAD0MMUmgA32DRCUkgrTQIegAmAGYygE5GXmgeXHq8UEgYXKlHZLRUSRh4ZHQVWpIyCmpaBmYcVTUISl8JgG5a+rYIKyQAWSQNYkllKbV1TR0BYXEpCLRFFCZlvCHifUMI-dq2YbWQJC0QYgBzehBYgiaB6MBgoI1aZ1PBcIA)

Comment: ... what? In your code you're trying to call `cosmisFunc` which doesn't exist, so it should error...

Comment: but in JS when call from child, method is found in parent so function gets call because exists in the object (its prototype)

Comment: What? Where do you define `cosmisFunc`? Is this a typo? Your child has `cosmicFunction` but not `cosmisFunc`...

Comment: sorry, typo there, thanks

Comment: Lastly, why are you doing this? This is obviously unsound since if Parent is not extended or is extended with a child that doesn't have the method, it will result in a runtime error.

Comment: long story short, because I am migrating some code to TS, and in JS works. So just thinking if `this` could be restricted to typescript somehow because the `cosmisFunc` will exist.

Comment: Ah so why not do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKOEzW) then?

Comment: if `this` is whatever (out of all the inheritance/extension hierarchy) the `cosmicFunc` wont exist, producing an error, so makes sense that typescript prevents you from doing that. But if `this` is an intance of something that is not that very same class, but a children `cosmicFunc` will exist

Comment: Sooo does adding it to the parent work or no...?

Comment: in the link you shared, error is gone, but you would be calling the Parent's `cosmisFunc` function wouldnt you? If you hover it says `(method) Parent.cosmisFunc(): void`. So would never be calling the child's one from the parent, which is what I'd like to tell to TS.

Comment: The child's method should have the same signature... this is perfectly fine.

Comment: in OOP makes total sense to have the error, because the parent is not the child type. But the point of my question is that would be nice to tell TS: "ey, `this` is not going to be 100 random, will be type me (`Parent`) or any of my children. So you can let the children instance properties into my type at compile time, because in JS the property is going to be found in the prototypal chain"

Comment: That's what my playground does, though? It has to be Parent or a child that has a `cosmisFunc` method.

Comment: if you run the code: `throw new Error("cannot call cosmisFunc on Parent");`. I want to call the Child `cosmicFuc` so that I obtain in the console `oh mama`

Comment: `new Child().someMethod();` achieves this... what are you asking for?

Comment: yes you are right. If you post your answer I'll accept it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just have the method on the parent and if it's called it should throw (to mimic the original behavior that when you call it, an error will be thrown):

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        
    }
    callChildFunction() {
        this.cosmisFunc()
    }
    cosmisFunc() {
        throw new Error("cannot call cosmisFunc on Parent");
    }
}
```

Then TS is happy since `this` will always have a `cosmisFunc`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKOEzW)